# How do opaque materials have an index of refraction?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

The index of refraction defines how much light is bent as it passes through an object, right? So how can opaque objects, which don't transmit light, have a value for the index of refraction? (e.g., Blender Docs lists the IoR of steel as 2.5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Index of refraction refers to the speed of light in a material, which comes up when determining how much light is reflected vs. refracted.  In an opaque material the refracted light is absorbed, but the intensity of reflection still depends on the illumination angle.

For example, light reflected at [Brewster's angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster's_angle) is completely polarized in the plane of the surface, because the angle between the reflected and refracted light is 90 degrees.  The effect is easy to see in the polished floor of a long hallway if you have polarizing sunglasses.  If you can find some physical polished steel and it has refractive index 2.5, you should see completely  polarized light reflected at a 22 degree angle from the horizontal.